# how to config governance registry and APIM to share registry

Tags: wso2, identity

all. I have some confusion about the registry.

1.the remote registry mount is done like this
 in [1]
but it is done like
 in [2] with the port NO. and /registry. are they the same??

2.I gonna install apim and IS and GREG, apim and IS should share their infomation, so that when a new tenant is registered in apim, IS should be able to use this new tenant too. My question is whether both the config and governance of both server should be configurated to GREG? because I don't know which (config or governance) folder contains the user resources?

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance453/Governance+Partition+in+a+Remote+Registry

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, If you wanted to share same tenant information then you need to share user store and the realm database. One way of doing that is, pointing to same ldap from all nodes and refering central database for realm.

- By default, IS has embedded ldap and if you do not have external/central ldap or user database that embedded ldap of IS can be use as the central user store. To do so, copy  element in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` and replace the  element of user-mgt.xml in other nodes. You need to change `ConnectionURL` appropriately with hostname and port. If you have started IS without any port offset and all nodes run on same server, you can use

`<Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property>`

or, if the IS run on some other machine having the ip 192.168.33.66 and start with portoffset 1, connection url would be like follows,

`<Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://192.168.33.66:10380</Property>`

- And you need to share registry database also. To do so create a central database and create a datasource with a name like `WSO2_REALM_DB` and refer to jndi name of that datasource in user-mgt xml by changing the property `<Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2_REALM_DB</Property>`. From [this](http://darray.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/add-new-mysql-secondary-user-store-in-identity-server-4-1-0/) post you can find steps to create database and configuring datasource for that db.

Its not clear on your first question but regarding registry mounting in general,

- Local partition is used to store resources specific to a node. And its
  usually do not shared among nodes.(ie. APIM node 1 may have local registry 1 and APIM node 2 have local registry 2 while IS node 1 have local registry 3)
- Config partition is used to store resources for specific product and its usually shared among nodes in same cluster. (ie. APIM node 1 may have config registry 1 and APIM node 2 also points to config registry 1 while IS node 1 have config registry 2)
- Governance partition is used to share resources among different products.(ie. APIM node 1, APIM node 2 and IS node 1 all points to same gov registry 1)

You can more detailed explanation in [this](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/) article.

Comment: Thanks, DarRay. We use Mysql for registry and user db now. And more clear with your explain. but I don't know why they use the remoteInstance tag in registry.xml, and how to config this parameter. Bacause I see no difference.